# Can Aws Rate limit be disabled only on specific ip?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-waf

In the `AWS ACLs` console, we are using a rule that limits the maximum number of API requests.

There were times when I had to make a request from my other server to a server that was restricted. Just in case, I want to disable this restriction only when requesting from my server's IP. Is it possible?

My Rule

[image: my Rules]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AWS WAF ACL actually works in a priority based order.

If you create a [IPSet rule](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/APIReference/API_IPSet.html) you can whitelist specific IP addresses (such as those servers you want to not be affected by the rate-based rule).

If you put this IPSet rule as the highest priority (at the top of the list), the rate-based rule will not be evaluated. This would make it easier to maintain as you would simply update this list as IPs need to be whitelisted to not be affected by rate limiting.

For more information take a look at the [How AWS WAF processes a web ACL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/web-acl-processing.html) page for a breakdown of how this processing works.

Comment: Which of the two is better: creating a new rule and adding the IP set, or excluding the IP set by adding NOT Match to the current rate limit rule?

Comment: Create a new rule and match specifically on those I would say.